# iCloud **Documents and Data** discontinued on iOS 9/Yosemite?

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, data-synchronization

I haven't been able to find a definite answer to this question.

I've upgraded my iOS devices to v9.0 and in both of them iOS "Documents and Data" is nowhere to be found. I got the prompt to upgrade to iCloud Drive, which I didn't do (*). When I installed iOS 8, I also didn't update and things worked as they did before.

Now I seem to be stuck in a weird limbo as Documents don't sync via iCloud but I haven't been able to find any definite answer on whether this is by design (I find it quite surprising as it's a bit of nowhere land). Or a weird iOS 9 bug.

Also, on the Mac/OSX front, is there any confirmation on whether Yosemite/El Capitán *only*support iCloud Drive too?

(*): I have a work Mac running Mavericks that I can't upgrade to Yosemite, and a Mac Mini on Snow Leopard that I have the feeling won't be able to run Yosemite with anything resembling reasonable performance.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you running a vintage iCloud Drive?  If you didn't update when promoted at 9 or before at 8?  That would be the first suspicion to me.

Comment: Hi, @Tyson. No, I didn't upgrade to iCloud Drive on any of my devices when upgrading/installing iOS 8 (and the different patches) or 9 -- precisely because of Mavericks compatibility (or rather lack of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that your intuition is correct: in iOS 9 and Yosemite (or later), you have the choice between iCloud Drive or no iCloud at all.

The reason for this is that "Documents & Data" syncing was re-written using the new CloudKit in iOS 8 and OS X 10.10, and renamed "iCloud Drive".

iOS 8 did remain backwards compatible with old-iCloud if you chose not to upgrade to iCloud Drive. One weird exception to this was the iPhone 6 and 6+. These devices did not have this compatibility mode, so it was iCloud Drive or nothing.

OS X Yosemite (10.10) also does *not* have the same compatibility mode though, so unless iCloud Drive was enabled, there is no document syncing. The same goes for OS X El Capitan (10.11).

I expect that the iOS 8 compatibility was only included to fill the gap between the time iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite shipped, so I cannot imagine that iOS 9 would be compatible with the old-iCloud in any way.

Also note that "iCloud" is a collection of different technologies under the surface, so things like Contacts and Calendar *may* be able to sync without iCloud Drive enabled on all devices, but most other apps will need it enabled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I'm not 100% in agreement here. I have an iPhone 6 and prior to upgrading to iOS 9 my iCloud with Documents and Data was happily chugging along.

Comment: Once we've moved to iOS 10/El Capitan, this seems moot anyhow... A bit of a PITA on the time when not all devices supported iCloud Drive, but now things appear to be working OK!